# How can I check if each row in a matrix is equal to an array and return a Boolean array containing the result?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

How can I check if each row in a matrix is equal to an array and return a Boolean array containing the result using NumPy? e.g.

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = np.array([4,5,6])

# Expected Result: [False,True,False]
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this question "_shows research effort_".

Comment: @takendarkk My best solution so far is below (I posted it as a potential answer), but I'd like to know if there's a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with the question's research effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The neatest way I've found of doing this, is:

```
result = np.all(a==b, axis=1)
```

Comment: You said you wanted a boolean array. Why are you using `astype(int)`?